# Embed youtube video Audio issue on iOS 11.2 inReact Native

Tags: react-native

I implemented Embed youtube video on react-native app android working good but, why getting the audio issue on Embed youtube video in react-native on ios 11.2?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Audio not coming volume also full increased.

Answer (score 0):

this working for me on ios 11.2 
`AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                      error:&setCategoryError];`